# Consuming WCF service (without metadata) on a non-.net platform

Tags: wcf, metadata

I have created a WCF service and hosted it through self hosting. This service doesn't have any metada published.

First Question

1. Can I consume it through Visual Studio, Add Service Reference? Hopefully not.
2. Can I consume it by creating manual proxy, i.e. `ChannelFactory<ServiceContract>`....?Hopefully yes.

Now in the second scenario, the client must be .Net, right?

So it implies that, to consume a wcf service on a non-.net platform, we have to expose its metadata?

Can't a WCF service without metadata, consume by Ajax client, or say Java client??

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 options to consume a WCF Service:

1. If the service exposes a WSDL use "add service reference" from VS (or an equivalent from another platform). Note that if you do not want to expose the WSDL you could expose it just temporarly, save the WSDL in a file, and then send it to user in any platform to generate proxy from it. You can turn off the WSDL immediately after you save it. Also note that even if the WSDL is not exposed still you need to protect the web service from unauthorized access.
2. If this is a .Net client it can compile with the same Service Contract assembly and use ChannelFactory etc.
3. Any platform can send raw soap message (e.g. XML) to the service. Of course they need to know what is the right format. A WSDL can help but even without it if they have a working sample they can imitate it.

Comment: by default WSDL is exposed on a GET endpoint like http://localhost/Service.svc?WSDL. If you have not changed this it is there. You can change it in the serviceMetadata element of the ServiceBehavior element. Mex is not required - it is just a fancy way to expose the WSDL using some protocols, the default GET is fine

Answer (score 1):

WCF provides REST (Representational State Transfer) support to consume it by non .NET client like JavaScript (AJAX), java, Objective C, web browser, etc...

Basically WCF REST is exposes methods and transferring data over the HTTP protocol and it supports all HTTP operations (GET, POST, PUT, and DELETE). This feature is making it platform independent as well as it doesn’t require metadata exposed.

Please refere below links to get more about WCF REST:

[An Introduction To RESTful Services With WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd315413.aspx)

[WCF REST Programming Model Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb412172%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

[WCF Rest vs. WCF SOAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh273094%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

[Create RESTful WCF Service API: Step By Step Guide](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/105273/Create-RESTful-WCF-Service-API-Step-By-Step-Guide)

Comment: FYI, SOAP based WCF also can be consumed by any client. The interoperability only depends on Transport Protocol being used.
Though you reply haven't match with my perspective, your Links helped me